# HTML - Footer places itself above container

Tags: html, css

I am creating a small webpage to practice my HTML on and I can't seem to figure out why the Footer just places itself at underneath the Header instead of underneath the container I have created.

It is most likely something small that I have overlooked but I can't seem to figure out or a find a solution anywhere so advice here would be greatly appreciated.

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 900px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
}

p,
h1,
h2,
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 900px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto;
  display: block;
}

main {
  padding: auto;
  display: block;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
}

#left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
}

#right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <p>Logo</p>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="left-column">
      <h1>Website title</h1>
      <h2>Article title</h2>
      <p>Some text followed by a list:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>A list item with a link (<a href="#">Click me</a>)</li>
        <li>New deals daily</li>
      </ul>
      <p> Some more text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
      <h2>Some content related to the article</h2>
      <div id="button">
        <p>A Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy;Website name 2017</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your footer to [clear the floated elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear) that come before it by adding `clear:both` to your CSS:

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  width: 900px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
}

p,
h1,
h2,
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 900px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto;
  display: block;
  clear:both;
}

main {
  padding: auto;
  display: block;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
}

#left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
}

#right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <p>Logo</p>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="left-column">
      <h1>Website title</h1>
      <h2>Article title</h2>
      <p>Some text followed by a list:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>A list item with a link (<a href="#">Click me</a>)</li>
        <li>New deals daily</li>
      </ul>
      <p> Some more text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
      <h2>Some content related to the article</h2>
      <div id="button">
        <p>A Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy;Website name 2017</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
}

p,
h1,
h2,
li {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: auto;
  display: block;

}

main {
  padding: auto;
  display: block;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#container {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
}

#left-column {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  float: left;
}

#right-column {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

#button {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 50px;
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <p>Logo</p>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="left-column">
      <h1>Website title</h1>
      <h2>Article title</h2>
      <p>Some text followed by a list:</p>
      <ul>
        <li>A list item</li>
        <li>A list item with a link (<a href="#">Click me</a>)</li>
        <li>New deals daily</li>
      </ul>
      <p> Some more text</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right-column">
      <h2>Some content related to the article</h2>
      <div id="button">
        <p>A Button</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>&copy;Website name 2017</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```